# Mysql FIND_In_SET return rows having all the values of that set

Tags: mysql

*********Thanx In ADvance*****************

I'm running this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `test_lab_mapping` tlm 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tlm.testID,'1,2')
```

And result is in this image:

[image: FIND THE RESULT OF THAT QUERY]

I want to get all `labId(COLUMN)` rows which have corresponding entries to ALL the  `testId(column)` which we will pass in `find_in_set` function. 
as per above query i passed `FIND_IN_SET(labId,'1,2')`;
its returning all the data right but with one extra row which has `labId = 3`
as `labId =1` has corresponding entry of `testId=1` and `testId=2` AND labId =2 has also same corresponding entries for both the testId 1 and 2 .

But `labId=3` has only corresponding entry to `testId=1` its does not have `testId = 2` entry so it should not come in result.

Comment: From all that I\`m guessing you need post aggregation filtering,which you tried to solve with FIND_IN_SET,but it`s not clear,at all.

Comment: dear can you please write the right query by using post aggregation filtering as i am new to mysql i dont have much knowledge about it thanx in adv #mihai

Comment: Your query does `FIND_IN_SET(testID, '1,2')`, not `FIND_IN_SET(labId, '1,2')`.

Answer (score 0):

`FIND_IN_SET` doesn't do this.

One way to do this is to use a join for each `testId` you want to include:

```
SELECT labId FROM test_lab_mapping WHERE testId = 1
  JOIN SELECT labId FROM test_lab_mapping WHERE testId = 2
  USING (labId)
```

This results in only those `labId` values that appear in both tests. The second `SELECT` in the join does not result in a row for `labId` = 3, as there is no row where `testId = 2` and `labId` = 3, so `labId` 3 does not appear in the result.

If you need to check more tests, add more `JOIN`ed selects:

```
SELECT labId FROM test_lab_mapping WHERE testId = 1
  JOIN SELECT labId FROM test_lab_mapping WHERE testId = 2
  JOIN SELECT labId FROM test_lab_mapping WHERE testId = 3
  ... etc
  USING (labId)
```